# send div id with ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, send

How do I send the id of my div with this same script!
like when a user sends the form, I want to send the id of de div too.
I want to make commentsystem for my pictures uploadssystem.

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comment=' + comment;

        if( comment=='')
        {
            alert('Please Give Valide Details');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
                url: "piccommentajax.php?id=<? echo $idcom ?>",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){

                    $("ol#show").append(html);
                    $("ol#show li:first").fadeIn("slow");
                    document.getElementById('comment').value='';
                    $("#name").focus();

                    $("#flash").hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with id of the div? Are you talking about the html id of the div or what?

Comment: You can get a div id using `$(div).attr('id')`.

Comment: yes like this <div id"23">content</div>

Comment: Why the random non-jQuery call?  `document.getElementById('comment').value=''`  Why not `$('#comment').val('')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you would do given your code:

```
datastring += '&divid=' + $('...').attr("id");
```

what you put in for the `...` makes all the difference. There's no way for us to know from the question.

Taking a wild *guess*, though? Try: `$(this).closest("div").attr("id");` This will get you the closest *enclosing* div to the clicked submit button.

Comment: wat i mean is i want to send the id of my